# Typescript Interface for value = key

Tags: typescript

New typescript user here.

We often declare our redux actions and other static constants like so (js):

```
export const notificationTypes = {
    WELCOME: "WELCOME",
    LOGGED_IN: 'LOGGED_IN',
    NEW_EMAIL: 'NEW_EMAIL',
};
```

I am trying to do the same with typescript:

```
export const notificationTypes = {
    WELCOME: "WELCOME",
    LOGGED_IN: 'LOGGED_IN',
    NEW_EMAIL: 'NEW_EMAIL',
};
export type NotificationType = keyof typeof notificationTypes;
```

And here is an attempt to use the new type:

```
import {notificationTypes, NotificationType} from "./notificationTypes"
interface Notification {
   type:NotificationType
}
//no errors
const firstNotificationTest:Notification={
    type:"WELCOME"
}

//error type 'string' is not assignable to type "WELCOME" | "LOGGED_IN" | "NEW_EMAIL"
const secondtNotificationTest:Notification={
    type:notificationTypes.WELCOME
}
```

As you can see, I can not use notificationTypes.WELCOME, but rather must use "WELCOME". This somewhat defeats the whole purpose of setting up these constants.

Is it possible to interface `Notification` to allow any `notificationTypes` value? Or interface `notificationTypes` itself so it knows that `value = key`? Or am I just using typescript completely wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to narrow down the properties of `notificationTypes` to their string literal types.

```
export const notificationTypes = {
    WELCOME: "WELCOME",
    LOGGED_IN: 'LOGGED_IN',
    NEW_EMAIL: 'NEW_EMAIL',
} as const
```

This also has the benefit, that the members are marked as `readonly`, so something like this cannot happen with normal type usage:

```
notificationTypes.LOGGED_IN = "duuuhh"
```

, so you effectively can use `notificationTypes` as replacement for a [conventional enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72RGBLAZthAQxxQBUBPMYVOAXjgG8AoOVuAdQFEAZAYQHkAspwBccAERc+QzuIA0LNt34BxFZwAiAfQCSAOTEByZWs269hhWzh7O7LZ0EBBHdyO37jl90tMAvnCENEhoMExMoJCwcDCUwDZYeATE2GRxdHAA1sDkELgxcXlwmDj4RCTIFFSoANzh2MgwwFC4hAjxeollKSiMigVUIp2lyRVVwP5MAPRTmHDNUNCoTCHocPhQ6MNJ5amV1DBDXaN7tMzWsYOSPALC4pPTUwvQA-GG6FANAOaGcNg0JUCqFQ2C+yEIACMADbxGAQV4SKS3WRwAA+EhM6m0+nEaIkHgczlc91W8FQwBCABMYNtumMDkcRrsUGd+q8RCUdj1KnFUAA6JEyB6cul7cb8zFmfQZcSUgCucoAFsrxEA)

Comment: Switched to using an `enum`, seems like the more typescript way to do it. Works like a charm now!